# Adding a while loop to make a user input rock paper scissors game repeat until the user ends the game

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Ok, so I have programmed a simple rock paper scissors game using user input to play. The user types their choice, a *random function* chooses the computers go and then a result is produced. After this the program is terminated because it has finished. I want to use a while loop so that when the game is finished, it starts again, and then the program will stop if the user types in *exit* or *quit*, which can easily be done by just saying something like while `playerGo != exit`, play the game blah blah. However, I cannot get this to work, can someone help me please, I'm a Java noob :)

```
import java.util.Scanner;   

public class RockPaperScissors{   
  public static void main(String[] args){  

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int compGoInt;
    String compGo;
    String playerGo;

    System.out.println("You can type 'Exit' to quit the game at any time.");
    System.out.print("Please enter your choice. Rock, Paper or Scissors: ");
    playerGo = input.nextLine();

    compGoInt = (int) (Math.random() * 3);

    switch (compGoInt){
    case 0:
        compGo = "Rock";
        break;
    case 1:
        compGo = "Paper";
        break;
    case 2:
        compGo = "Scissors";
        break;
    default:
        compGo = "Error";
        System.out.println("Error.");
        break;
    }

    if (playerGo.equals(compGo)){
        System.out.println("Computer chooses "+compGo);
        System.out.println("It's a draw!");
    }

    else if ((playerGo.equalsIgnoreCase("Rock") && compGo.equalsIgnoreCase("Scissors")) ||
            (playerGo.equalsIgnoreCase("Paper") && compGo.equalsIgnoreCase("Rock")) ||
            (playerGo.equalsIgnoreCase("Scissors") && compGo.equalsIgnoreCase("Paper"))){
        System.out.println("Computer chooses "+compGo);
        System.out.println("Player Wins!");
    }

    else if ((compGo.equalsIgnoreCase("Rock") && playerGo.equalsIgnoreCase("Scissors")) ||
            (compGo.equalsIgnoreCase("Paper") && playerGo.equalsIgnoreCase("Rock")) ||
            (compGo.equalsIgnoreCase("Scissors") && playerGo.equalsIgnoreCase("Paper"))){
        System.out.println("Computer chooses "+compGo);
        System.out.println("Computer Wins!");
    }

    else{
        System.out.println("Something has gone wrong!");
        System.out.println("Player chose "+playerGo);
        System.out.println("Computer chose "+compGo);
    }


}
```

}

Comment: `...just saying something like while playerGo != exit` Note that it should be `!playerGo.equals("exit")` (or something). Can you show us the code you tried and explain why it failed? You will likely to get better answers - since they will also tell you where did you go wrong.

Comment: What have you tried? Where have you put the loop? What kinds of errors or incorrect behavior did you see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put:

```
while(true) {
     if(playerGo.equalsIgnoreCase("Exit")) break;
     else //GameLogic
}
```

Though, if I may say so, you should have the user choose a number, since any letter input is prone to errors.

For clarification purposes:

```
import java.util.Scanner;   

public class RockPaperScissors{   
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int compGoInt;
        String compGo;
        String playerGo;

        while(true) {
            System.out.println("You can type 'Exit' to quit the game at any time.");
            System.out.print("Please enter your choice. Rock, Paper or Scissors: ");
            playerGo = input.nextLine();

            if(playerGo.equalsIgnoreCase("Exit")) break;    //Checks for exit condition.
            else { //GameLogic

                compGoInt = (int) (Math.random() * 3);

                switch (compGoInt){
                case 0:
                    compGo = "Rock";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    compGo = "Paper";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    compGo = "Scissors";
                    break;
                default:
                    compGo = "Error";
                    System.out.println("Error.");
                    break;
                }

                if (playerGo.equals(compGo)){
                    System.out.println("Computer chooses "+compGo);
                    System.out.println("It's a draw!");
                }

                else if ((playerGo.equalsIgnoreCase("Rock") && compGo.equalsIgnoreCase("Scissors")) ||
                        (playerGo.equalsIgnoreCase("Paper") && compGo.equalsIgnoreCase("Rock")) ||
                        (playerGo.equalsIgnoreCase("Scissors") && compGo.equalsIgnoreCase("Paper"))){
                    System.out.println("Computer chooses "+compGo);
                    System.out.println("Player Wins!");
                }

                else if ((compGo.equalsIgnoreCase("Rock") && playerGo.equalsIgnoreCase("Scissors")) ||
                        (compGo.equalsIgnoreCase("Paper") && playerGo.equalsIgnoreCase("Rock")) ||
                        (compGo.equalsIgnoreCase("Scissors") && playerGo.equalsIgnoreCase("Paper"))){
                    System.out.println("Computer chooses "+compGo);
                    System.out.println("Computer Wins!");
                }

                else{
                    System.out.println("Something has gone wrong!");
                    System.out.println("Player chose "+playerGo);
                    System.out.println("Computer chose "+compGo);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does this while loop go? If I put it before the whole thing, I have the problem that the playerGo variable is not declared, but if I put it after it just gives me my error message from the else statement. Thanks :)

Comment: @Daniel I copied your entire code and put the loop at the appropriate location. You could also move the loop down two lines, if you don't want the instructions to be printed ever time, but input.nextLine() HAS to be inside the loop.

Comment: Oh I see, I had not added in a break when I tried to add a while loop myself, and I have the != boolean operator instead of equals. This worked perfectly how I wanted it to, thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Daniel You're welcome. Please don't forget to accept an answer if you're satisfied with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a boolean variable IsGameRunning = true.
wrap the whole login in a while loop that checks the state of IsGameRunning.
Add a case to the switch statement that checks for user input "-1", and when the user enters "-1" as input the case changes IsGameRunning variable to false.

Simple and should work

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean running = true;
do{
    System.out.println("You can type 'Exit' to quit the game at any time.");
    System.out.print("Please enter your choice. Rock, Paper or Scissors: ");
    playerGo = input.nextLine();
    running = !(playerGo.equalsIgnoreCase('Exit') || playerGo.equalsIgnoreCase('Quit'));
    if(running){
       //logic
       compGoInt = (int) (Math.random() * 3);
       ...
    }
}while(running)
```

do while -> input needs to be asked at least once.

and for

```
if (playerGo.equals(compGo)){
     System.out.println("Computer chooses "+compGo);
     System.out.println("It's a draw!");
 }
```

`playerGo.equals(compGo)` -> `playerGo.equalsIgnoreCase(compGo)` like the rest of your code